# Как подчеркнуть текст кастомно?

Tags: java, android, xml

Как в подчеркнуть текст кастомно?

[image: задача]

Comment: не имеет? почему? мне нужно это сделать для android в android studio

Comment: Не имеет, потому что заниматься разработкой под андроид можно и вовсе без андроид студио, и вовсе без любой другой среды разработки. И реализовать то, что на картинке, можно кучей самых разных способов.

Comment: Я думаю человек просто не смог грамотно сформулировать вопрос, так как далек от предметной области. Я считаю что сообщество stackoverflow могло подсказать и объяснить что не так.

Comment: @pavlofff Вы правы. Видел ваши ответы, они действительно объемные, качественный и поясняют суть проблемы и конечно тяжело каждый раз отвечать одно и тоже. Возможно ли как то улучшить систему поиска схожих вопросов? Мне кажется эта основная проблема. Т.к. с RecyclerView схожая беда, ответил на один вопрос еще один такой же спустя 2 дня.  Конкретно этого вопроса, у меня есть подозрение, что человек не разработчик и просто решил сам попробовать что-то поменять в своем проекте.. Я просто предположил или не знает что такое IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

наконец раборался сам.

deshed.xml

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item

    android:gravity="center"
    android:width="65dp"
    android:height="5dp"


    >
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke


            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#ffd216" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

затем просто подключил xml 
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/dashed"

Comment: я тока начал разработку на android. до этого подобным не занимался. спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 6):

Существует три способа это сделать:

1. SpannableString
2. setPaintFlags()
3. Html.fromHtml()

**1-ый способ:**

Для подчеркивания текста вы используете [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

```
String udata="Underlined Text";
SpannableString content = new SpannableString(udata);
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, udata.length(), 0);
mTextView.setText(content);
```

**2-ой способ:**

Вы можете использовать метод `SetPaintFlags` для `TextView`, чтобы подчеркнуть текст TextView.

```
mTextView.setPaintFlags(mTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
mTextView.setText("This text will be underlined");
```

**3-ий способ:**

Используя `Html.fromHtml (htmlString)`;

```
String htmlString="<u>This text will be underlined</u>";
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

**или**

```
txtView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>underlined</u> text"));
```